# Getting exact duplicate rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am looking for exact duplicate content in MySQL. There are a lot of columns, around 30-40 long columns per row. There seem to be some duplicated rows and I would like to identify them. There are a lot of records.

Is there any way to get MySQL to return all rows that are duplicated where every single column is the same, without listing and creating a query that lists every column?

Comment: Can you post some sample of your data so that we can look further into? The question seems too vague without seeing the table and data.

Comment: Nope, but you're averse to typing, even MySQL workbench can give you a full select as a starting point.

Comment: "and I would like to identify them" - You can't. You can only identify a row by a unique (or primary) key. But if you had that, there wouldn't be any exact duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and I would like to identify them

You can't. You can only identify a row by a unique (or primary) key. But if you had that, there wouldn't be any exact duplicates.

However - If you realy don't want to list all columns, you could create a temporary copy of the table and add an AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY. Then a combination of a `NATURAL JOIN`, `GROUP BY` and `COUNT` will return you the duplicated rows:

```
drop table if exists my_duplicates;
create table my_duplicates (c1 int, c2 int, c3 int);
insert into my_duplicates(c1, c2, c3)values
    (1,1,1),
    (1,2,3),
    (4,5,6),
    (1,2,3);

drop temporary table if exists tmp;
create temporary table tmp as select * from my_duplicates;
alter table tmp add column row_number int auto_increment primary key;

select tmp.*
from tmp
natural join my_duplicates
group by tmp.row_number
having count(*) > 1
```

Result:

```
c1 | c2 | c3 | row_number
---|----|----|-----------
 1 |  2 |  3 |          2
 1 |  2 |  3 |          4
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/COQA38406

#### Update

If you have a primary key column, you can just do the opposite: Make a copy of the table and drop the primary key column in the copy table. Then you have the same situation as above - You just need to switch the tables in the query.

```
drop table if exists my_duplicates;
create table my_duplicates (id int auto_increment primary key, c1 int, c2 int, c3 int);
insert into my_duplicates(c1, c2, c3)values
    (1,1,1),
    (1,2,3),
    (4,5,6),
    (1,2,3);

drop temporary table if exists tmp;
create temporary table tmp as select * from my_duplicates;
alter table tmp drop column id;

select t.*
from my_duplicates t
natural join tmp
group by t.id
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Wouldn't that also join rows to themselves?

Comment: Sorry @PaulSpiegel you are right, they are not exactly duplicates I guess because I do already have a primary key auto increment. Does this make it easier?

Comment: @Skintest - Well with a PK you can at least **identify** the rows.  But to find the duplicate rows (without listing all the columns), you will need to do quite the same.

Comment: Thanks @PaulSpiegel still working on this but will accept your answer as it helped me understand this better